# In what countries is research fraud considered a crime?

Tags: publications, legal-issues

I'm interested in knowing what countries is research fraud considered a crime.  I'm specifically referring to any type of research dishonesty, such as publishing a knowingly fraudulent paper or data.  For example, buying an authorship position on a paper from a research paper mill -- would that be a crime?

Comment: A quick Google search returns results focusing on "Should research fraud be considered a crime?", and none of these mention any countries where it is already considered a crime. Though not conclusive, this does suggest that considering research fraud a crime is far from widespread.

Comment: [A](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25715528/) [few](https://www.cmaj.ca/content/187/17/1273) [interesting](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11019-018-9865-7) [links](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1747016119898400).

Comment: A fraud that led directly to a death would probably be construed as (involuntary) manslaughter.

Comment: Perhaps better on Law SE. This is also asking for a big list (well, maybe not so big).

Answer (score -1):

This usually falls under other crimes, depending on the specific case. The most likely crimes are **plagiarism** and various kinds of **forgery** depending on the jurisdiction. There are other crimes that can be triggered as well, such as **fraud** and Intellectual Property Rights (IPR) copyright violation, ending in the general piracy crimes.
Each case needs to be investigated properly to identify the correct jurisdictions and related crimes (if any), so it is not possible to make a general statement about which crime is configured.

Comment: Where is plagiarism a crime? Not copyright violation, but actual misattribution of _ideas_.

Comment: Hi @Buffy, just to mention one jurisdiction I am familiar with, in Italy the article 171-bis of the Act #633 of 22 April 1941 (consolidated on 6 Feb 2016 by the Dlgs #8 on 15 Jan 2016) establishes up to a year in prison for a person that makes a profit from somebody else intellectual work. Before voting down, please at least inform yourself.

Comment: I didn't vote down. Sorry you are thinking that. I asked a question only. FWIW, I only downvote answers that would be dangerous advice for the OP. Yours is not.

Comment: Making a profit from someone else's intellectual work isn't necessarily plagiarism if it is attributed. I think it must be more nuanced. Everyone in the software industry makes a profit off of the intellectual work of computer language designers, of course.

Comment: @Buffy, indeed, as I clearly mention, each case is different and has to be evaluated on the basis of the jurisdiction, the possible monetary/financial gain, the weight of the misrepresentation and so on. It goes from being frowned upon up to huge fines and years in prison depending on all those parameters. BTW, sorry for assuming you voted this down :)